# Why do I get "Unable to connect to SQL Server Database" when using aspnet_regsql in a server environment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I recently ran into an issue when using aspnet_regsql in our environment. Locally, I didn't have any problem using the following command line.

```
"%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe" -S server\instance -E -ssadd -sstype p
```

However, when I move to our server environments, I get the following failure message.

An error has occurred. Details of the exception: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

**Unable to connect to SQL Server database.**

Answer (score 1):

I had a hunch that aspnet_regsql was using a different port than the default 1433. After using wireshark, I confirmed my suspicion and it was using 1434 which locally had no problem but since in a server environment, we need to explicitly request to open port, it was close by default.

The fix was simple enough which was to explicitly specify the port **-S server\instance,1433**